# Is this EVM high-level definition valid?

Tags: blockchain, evm

I have a problem understanding Ethereum's fundamental concept of EVM.

**Is EVM an identical VM created by each user(node) in their enviroment(PC) which has a specific architecture(state etc, I get that), and each user "works" on it by trying to follow the strict rules that the architecture specifies?**

That's the simplistic explanation I arrived at after hours of reading about it.

I understand that there are a lot of intermediate things that need to be said for this definition to be complete but at the specific moment, I am looking for a high-level explanation.

I am trying to get my fundamentals on solid ground before getting into the more advanced topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ethereum Virtual Machine is in fact very simple system and in its core is is just a code interpreter. In fact, it consists of Program Counter (PC), Execution Stack, Memory and Gas Counter. In addition it also has a reference to the EVM code and Contract Account Storage. Every full node on the Ethereum network runs the instance of EVM and every single active node executed all of the broadcasted transactions to verify that it has the same state as all other nodes - that is how we reach consensus in the terms of the data accuracy, everyone has to have the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer @Boki XD. Just to clarify, as I stated it is in fact a Virtual Machine (simple as you explained in a great manner, and thanks for that) that everyone has an instance of. So per my understanding, my definition stands valid (even if its not detailed enough)?

Comment: More clear, it's a good base definition to have in my mind for EVM as i wander through the eth universe, right? Thanks in advance @Boki XD

Comment: I find your definition a bit vague, and would maybe put is simply like this. You can think of this EVM as a small dumb computer that executes smart contracts. It only does that - takes instruction by instruction and runs it. Every Ethereum client has that small computer that does this execution of the contracts. That small computer is equal for every Ethereum node - or better said, does the same thing. Hope this help and would appreciate if you accept my answer.

Comment: Great, now I'm covered. Respect.